# Matlab functions string arguments followed by sequence of variables

Tags: matlab, function

How do you create a function in matlab for example:

```
[pos, speed]=my_function('position',1,2,4,5.2,'speed',50,1)
```

such that

```
pos = [1,2,4,5.2]
```

and

```
speed = [50,1]
```

and empty vectors if no values was entered?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Varargin will help you: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get the functionality using `nargin` and `varargin` like this:

```
function [position, speed] = my_function(varargin)
   if nargin == 8
      position = cell2mat(varargin(2:5));
      speed = cell2mat(varargin(7:8));
   else
   position = [];
   speed = [];
end
```

This function does literally what you asked for, but don't let it fool you: That doesn't make it a "good" function. You'll need to do a lot more work in order to make it robust and otherwise good. I'll leave that part up to you.

Good luck =)